# How to find all views and panels that use a certain field

Tags: views, entities, panels

I want to delete a field but I am not sure if there is still a view or a panel somewhere on the site that is still using it. So I want to know if there is any possibility to find all views and panels that use a certain field?

Answer (score 2):

In D7, you can see this for views at least at
/admin/reports/fields/views-fields (Admin -> Reports -> Field list -> Used in views)

(Similarly for content types it is at
/admin/reports/fields/ (Admin -> Reports -> Field list)

Don't know about panels though.

Comment: +1, this is what my comment was about, but I couldn't look up the details right away.

Comment: yes, sorry to not refer to your comment.

Comment: No worries, you posted a good answer, that's what matters. :)

Comment: The only thing I have to add is that I don't think the functionality exists in Panels. Since both Views and Panels uses Ctools heavily for abstraction of Drupals APIs however, it's entirely possible that it would be an easy adaptation.

Answer (score -1):

This module may help you [Field Tools](https://drupal.org/project/field_tools)

It will allow you to see an overview of fields with links to edit single instances, and all instances at once.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be useful to the OP in any way at all?